# Custom fileds in PayPal Smart Payment Buttons

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am integrating the new Paypal Smart Payment Buttons in my website.
 Can i pass custom variables in request and they send back in paypal reply?
 My js code is below

```
paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [
                    {
                        reference_id: "PUHF",
                        description: "Some description",
                        custom_id: "Something7364",
                        soft_descriptor: "Great description 1",
                        my_filed1 : "filed 1 value",
                        my_filed2 : "filed 2 value",
                        my_filed3 : "filed 3 value",
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: '50.00',
                            breakdown: {
                                item_total: {
                                    currency_code: "USD",
                                    value: '50.00'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                ]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
                // Call your server to save the transaction
                console.log(details);

            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Comment: You're using the client-side method. It might be best to make the createOrder and onApprove calls from your web server (PayPal have docs for server-side integrations). You can pass the custom fields to your web server for processing. You have tagged javascript and php. What type of backend do you have?

Comment: @Fuller PHP on servers side

Comment: I would look into the PayPal SDK for PHP. Follow their documentation on how to implement server side functionality.

Comment: @Fuller Nice Answer